# Detect and remove excess solid color padding around and NSImage

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I'm trying to build an macos utility to help me center the content of the image and not sure how I would achieve such. For example let say that I have an image as below:

[image]

As you can see there's more white space on the right side of the image, what I'm trying to do is to detect that there's more white space there and trim those so that the amount of white space on both sides (left and right) are equal, making the content of the image center.

Obviously it should apply for both vertical and horizontal axis. I'm new to macos programming so any pointers/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is an image processing problem. In order to do that with any speed, you'd really need to load the image into memory and walk the pixel buffer, looking for the bounds of the image inside the solid color border. Conceptually it's not that difficult but the code is fussy to write.

Comment: Yea I reckon I could go down that path of walking the pixels. But I was wondering if there's framework/libraries out there that do that, this is surely not a new problem? I'm trying to not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: There may well be a library that does what you want. Unfortunately this site frowns on questions that ask for such things.